# Bitcoin library in python

Tags: python, library

I need a good library for bitcoin and other BTC-like cryptocurrencies in python.
I'm looking for something similar to [bitcoinjs](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) but in python. 
Minimal requirements:

- generate an EC keypair and get public address from the public key
- generate an EC keypair and compress it to WIF format.
- get an EC keypair from WIF
- generate a number of EC keypairs (a HD wallet) from a given seed
- build a transaction
- broadcast transaction

If you know any good cryptocurrency libraries let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Peter Todd's [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib).

From the github repo:

> This Python2/3 library provides an easy interface to the bitcoin data structures and protocol. The approach is low-level and "ground up", with a focus on providing tools to manipulate the internals of how Bitcoin works.

Answer (score 1):

Check-out the node-directory [within my Github repo](https://github.com/alexanderjsingleton/crypto-cuck-coin) experimenting with a scalable cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://pybtc.readthedocs.io , pybtc python bitcoin library